# How to call fragment from adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

I want to call fragment from adapter but in that fragment adapter is not called, this is totally different fragment.

SongListAdapter.java

```
private TopRatedFragment fragment;
public void onClick(View v) {
fragment.onItemClick(songs.getVideoUrl();
}
```

TopRatedFragment.java

```
mAdapter = new SongsListAdapter(getActivity(),songsList,TopRatedFragment.this);
```

SingleVideoFragment.java

```
public class SingleVideoFragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlevideo, container, false);
  return view;
}
public void onItemClick(String VideoUrl) 
 {`
   enter code here`
 }
```

I want to call onItemClick() method of SingleVideoFragment from SongsListAdapter and SongsListAdapter is called from TopRatedFragment which is working fine.

Comment: So both fragment in resume stage with its own containers. right?

Comment: Sorry, not getting what you want to say?

Comment: I mean to say, you have one activity with two different container and every container has two different fragment and which is on userview. right?

Comment: No, Both fragment are in same container

Comment: so it is not possible. how can you refer the object when it is dead. it leads to deadobject exception or null object exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very easy: I declared onItemClick() method in TopRatedFragment. In onItemClick() method I called SingleVideoFragment and called required method in onCreateView() of SingleVideoFragment .